# Significance of valueOf() in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, value-of

I have noticed the snippet_1 in the implementation of one of the Node API's. Snippet_2 has been written by me. I don't feel much difference between them. Is there really any significance of using `valueOf()` function. 
And also, we can notice a property called as `valueOf` which would return `[Function: valueOf]`

**Snippet_1**

```
Buffer.from = function from(value, encodingOrOffset, length) {
    const valueOf = value.valueOf && value.valueOf();
      if (valueOf !== null && valueOf !== undefined && valueOf !== value)
        return Buffer.from(valueOf, encodingOrOffset, length);

}
```

**Snippet_2**

```
Buffer.from = function from(value, encodingOrOffset, length) {
  if (value !== null && value !== undefined)
    return Buffer.from(value, encodingOrOffset, length);

}
```

Comment: What happens in the else case? Can you please link the implementation where you found this for some context?

Comment: It really should have been `const valueOf = typeof value.valueOf == "function" ? value.valueOf() : null`, otherwise this fails on objects with custom `valueOf` data properties.

Comment: "*I don't feel much difference between them.*" - Isn't the difference obvious? The two snippets do very different things. Do you really think they have the same outcome on all possible values?

Comment: @Bergi : 
https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f52ccc828c26aee8fe78c82a8a23fabd21918b7/lib/buffer.js#L161

Comment: Well the check in your proposed implementation is unnecessary since [that case](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/8f52ccc828c26aee8fe78c82a8a23fabd21918b7/lib/buffer.js#L196) is always true.

Comment: Now when that is the only code in a function it even makes less sense.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an object wrapper and you want to get the underlying primitive value out, you should use the `valueOf()` method. This is called **Unboxing**.

All normal objects have the built-in Object.prototype as the top of the prototype chain (like the global scope in scope look-up), where property resolution will stop if not found anywhere prior in the chain. `toString()`, `valueOf()`, and several other common utilities exist on this Object.prototype object, explaining how all objects in the language are able to access them.

Assume the following example:

```
var i = 2;

Number.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return i++;
};

var a = new Number( 42 );

if (a == 2 && a == 3) {
    console.log( "Yep, this happened." );
}
```

Will this behave the same way with your snipper? The answer is no.